# Autohotkey and ExitApp: how to enable and disable ESC key to work just in a part of the script?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a very long script and I want to stop it with ESC key if it goes astray.

So I have put in the script this line:

```
Esc::ExitApp
```

But, of course, sometimes I have to press ESC key even when not running the script and when I need AutoHotkey, it's gone.

How do I tie ExitApp to ESC key just for a part of the script that's running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code is working:

```
Esc::goto ExitThisProgramQuestion

ExitThisProgramQuestion:
    MsgBox, 4, , Are we exiting? 
    IfMsgBox, No
        return
    ExitApp
return
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `ExitApp` as a command in your script!  It is a special kind of label, not a function.  If the label doesn't exist in your script, you can't call it.

To make it exist, just add another line with the label on it.  -->>**actually, I was wrong to say that.  In the docs it gives the example that you can use simply `Esc::ExitApp` just like that to exit the running script  `ExitApp` exists in the script even if you don't create it first because it's built into AutoHotkey.  However, with your new code from your comment, you can use a custom label (which does have to exist in your script before you can call it):

```
Esc::goto DoSomething

DoSomething:
    MsgBox, 4, , Are we exiting? 
    IfMsgBox, No
        return  ;after this return, the next line will not be called.
    ExitApp  ;as soon as this is called, the script ends completely and no more of the script will ever be called
return
```

Comment: What am I doing wrong, this procedure never runs although AutoHotkey quits?    

Esc::ExitApp ;     

ExitApp  

{  
    MsgBox, 4, , Are we exiting?  

    IfMsgBox, No  

    return  

}

Comment: You can't do it that way. (sorry so long - I was on vacation).  `ExitApp` is a special command label.  I'll update my answer with your new code here.

Comment: Sigh.
Error.DoSomething - this line does not contain a recognised action

Comment: Sorry - there was one two many colons in `DoSomething`.  Two colons denote a hotkey; one colon denotes a label.  I fixed it in the code - I'm surprised nobody caught that.

Comment: Hi, I'm really a beginner.  Now all I get is: Dosomething - Error: This line does not contain recognized action. :(

Comment: I'm sorry!  the `return` should have been on its own line.  Okay, try it again.  syntax...  However, you know that `exitapp` only exits the running script, right?  If you want to exit another program you have to use something else.

Comment: You are welcome; sorry for the typos and the trouble.  Once you write a few complex scripts in autohotkey, you'll be able to understand the syntax just by looking.  autohotkey is really fun.